# wordpress search bar for page that search only particular page id's

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i create a search bar in a page that searches only in particular page id's. This shouldn't affect the search bar in other pages.

I tried

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'pregetposts_forspecificpage' );

function pregetposts_forspecificpage($query){
   if ($query->is_search) {
   $query->set('post_type', 'page');
   $query->set('post__in', array(22103,22121));
   }
   return $query;
}
```

But it affects search bars in other pages. How can i accomplish this ?

Comment: In your form for that search bar add two hidden fields, in theory (I am not 100% sure without checking) called 'post_type' and 'post__in' with their values matching your query (the array can just be comma separated values not an array. These values then get posted with the search and act as filters.